# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, canvas

Вставил код на JSHint никакой ошибки, но браузер выдаёт

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at app.js:2

в чём может быть проблема?

```
1. var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
2. var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



var ground = new Image();
ground.src = 'img/ground.png';


var food = new Image();
food.src = 'img/food.png';



var box = 32;

var score = 0;


function drawGame() {
    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0,0);
}

var game = setInterval(drawGame, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня всё хорошо, проверьте ID у канваса

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx); // CanvasRenderingContext2D { ... }
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Если ID не помогла тогда вставьте `<script>` в конец документа. У вас запуск скрипта происходит раньше рендера документа

Comment: ошибка оказалась в id canvas. Вместо game было написано name. Спасибо вам

Comment: Не за что рад помочь